# Total Terminal opens new tab separately in macOS High Sierra

Tags: terminal, high-sierra

I've been using Total Terminal (former Visor) for a while now. With the new High Sierra update to osx when I try to open a new tab with <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> it ends up opening it like a new window, separately from the sticky tab I already have opened. I have to mention that it worked great on Sierra.

I've checked the settings and I have "open with same profile" and "open in same working directory" checked. Also I've entered Recovery Mode and set the `csrutil enable --without debug` which Total Terminal needs starting from El Capitan.

The [Total Terminal web page](https://totalterminal.binaryage.com/) says it's not currently under development and High Sierra is not listed under Compatibility.

If anyone managed to find a fix around this, it'll be highly appreciated. If not, I'm thinking about switching to iTerm2. Apparently the developer of Total Terminal recommends doing so too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It's time to move over to iTerm2.**  It's highly unlikely a fix will be found in the wild because it doesn't make sense to do so.

**It's no longer under active development**.  From the About page on their [website](https://totalterminal.binaryage.com/)

[image]

**SIP must be disabled to use**.  (IMO), disabling SIP to get a non-critical app to function is not a wise path to pursue.  SIP adds a layer of protection to your system that isn't worth disabling for a terminal app.  From their [web page specifically on SIP](https://totalterminal.binaryage.com/#sip)

> System Integrity Protection (SIP) is a new security feature introduced
>   by Apple. That's good, but unfortunately it prevents TotalTerminal
>   from augmenting Terminal. This article will tell you how to configure
>   your machine, so that you can use TotalTerminal. Before you do this,
>   it is important to get informed about what System Integrity Protection
>   is, and what it means to turn it off. Technical details are well
>   covered in SIP review on Ars Technica. Apple also provided some
>   information here.

**And finally, the note from the developer himself:**

> Do you really depend on TotalTerminal workflows so much that you want
>   to possibly lower your system security? Frankly, I'm going to stop
>   TotalTerminal development because I have personally switched to iTerm
>   2. It offers similar functionality to Visor and comparable features to build-in Terminal.app.

**TL;DR**

Total Terminal requires you to disable  security.  It would be counter productive to find/create/bodge a workaround when ultimately you would end up with an insecure system when there are already excellent alternatives (like [iTerm2](https://iterm2.com/)) that don't have this vulnerability/flaw/drawback.

Comment: I was already 90% sure about the iterm2 switch before the post, but wanted one last chance with totalTerminal bc I got used to it. Took me like 30 minutes to configure iterm2 like I'm used to interact with it. Nevertheless, I don't feel any drawbacks after switching, the transition has been pretty smooth. Marking this as the correct answer as nobody else responded.